# Fairplay SDK and IOS9

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, fairplay

I have used the Fairplay sdk on IOS8.4.1 and now I have updated my IPad that I test with to IOS9

So to be super clear I am using: 
OSX 10.10.5 (14F27) 
XCode 7.0 (7A220)
IPad2 mini IOS9

Using the test client that comes with the sdk, I just did a clean and rebuild did not change anything in the source code that worked fine on IOS8, no its not even close to working, it never gets to the
shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource function.
All I get is:
 error -1022, operation could not be completed

It does this on both the encrypted video and the unencrypted video that comes with the Fairplay SDK.

So my question is, has any one successfully played the encrypted video using the dev sdk credentials?

Comment: Any news about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They've updated their entire SDK. People like [everycord](http://everycord.net) EveryCord app cracked apples new sdk most likely via the MFISapV2 chip on board the iOS device. I've spoken to some companies who have spent lots of money researching this (I'm not talking $1,000 I'm talking $100k's) so it's definitely a closely guarded secret.